# CRON: Difference between "At minute 0" and "Every 60 minute"

Tags: unix, cron

What is the difference between "At minute 0":  `0 * * * *`
and "Every 60 minute": `0/60 * * * *`

Are these two represent the same schedule? I need to start job at the beginning of every hour and have found both in different sources, this is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. If you divide 0 to 60 you will get 0. And the canonical records which will work in UNIX and linux is:

```
0 * * * * command
```

because many (if not all) Unix OS do not understand records like `something/other` in `cron`